# How to include all months of a year in query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table :

```
ID1  ID2  ID3    DATE     VALUE
  1   1    1     APR-18    5
```

I want to get the rows for the missing months :
Suppose I am considering the year 2018 ,
so my output should look like this :

```
ID1    ID2  ID3    DATE     VALUE
 1      1    1     JAN-18    0
 1      1    1     FEB-18    0
 1      1    1     MAR-18    0
 1      1    1     APR-18    5
 1      1    1     MAY-18    0
 1      1    1     JUN-18    0
 1      1    1     JUL-18    0
 1      1    1     AUG-18    0
 1      1    1     SEP-18    0
 1      1    1     OCT-18    0
 1      1    1     NOV-18    0
 1      1    1     DEC-18    0
```

I tried cross join with this :

```
select add_months(date '2018-01-01', level - 1) as month
  from dual
  connect by level <=12
```

but this does not give the intended result .
Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your subquery returns the months of the year correctly. You haven't posted your whole query so not sure why you say it doesn't work. Anyway, here's how to finagle a cross join to get the results you want:

```
with cal as (
  select add_months(date '2018-01-01', level - 1) as month
  from dual
  connect by level <=12
  )
select t23.id1
       , t23.id2
       , t23.id3
       , to_char(cal.month, 'MON-YY') as dt
       , case when to_char(cal.month, 'MON-YY') = t23.dt
          then t23.val
          else 0 end as val
from cal
     cross join t23
order by cal.month;
```

And [a SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fdaa34/3) to prove it works.

Comment: Hi APC ,The ouput of your query gives 1 1 1 APR-18 0
1 1 1 APR-18 0
1 1 1 APR-18 0
1 1 1 APR-18 5
1 1 1 APR-18 0
1 1 1 APR-18 0
1 1 1 APR-18 0
1 1 1 APR-18 0
1 1 1 APR-18 0
1 1 1 APR-18 0
1 1 1 APR-18 0
1 1 1 APR-18 0

Comment: Hi APC,yes I replaced that with cal.month .But I was not allowed to edit in 5 mins

Answer (score -1):

Please use this to get correct answer

```
    WITH DateYear AS
    (
    SELECT 0 AS num
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT num + 1 FROM DateYear 
    WHERE num < 11
    )
    select id1,id2,id3,
    case when dd.date1 = dt then dt else '0' end
    dt,
    case when dd.date1 = dt then val else '0' end
    val from (
    SELECT CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(MONTH,num,CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS vARCHAR))) AS Date2
    ,  Upper(CONVERT(CHAR(3), CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(MONTH,num,CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS vARCHAR))), 100))+'-'+ Right               (CONVERT(CHAR(4), CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(MONTH,num,CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS vARCHAR))), 120) ,2) date1
     from DateYear ) dd 
     cross join t23
```

Comment: Why are you giving me -1 vote in above solution they fixed the date(HARD CODE) and on over the year they have to change it but in my solution there is not need to set hard code date in .

Comment: It's because you have used SQL Server syntax when the question is taggedp `[oracle]`. The `[sql]` tag means SQL language not MSSQL. Different products use different functions and date functions are a particular area of divergence.